# prestashop copy on localhost with virtualhost settings redirects to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https, prestashop, virtualhost

I does not prestashop before. I got a copy from server, backed up the live database and went to localhost.

Im using xampp 3.2.2, Im using win10

1. I made a folder "whatisthis" where I placed copied prestashop
2. Created database in phpmyadmin, and imported database
3. Modified database settings in settings.inc.php
4. Added new line in **hosts** file

   127.0.0.1       myprestashop.com

Added

```
<VirtualHost myprestashop.com> 
    DocumentRoot "D:/_jsys/htdocs/whatisthis"
    ServerName myprestashop.com
    ServerAlias *.myprestashop.com
   <Directory "D:/_jsys/htdocs/whatisthis">
            Options All
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

into **httpd-vhosts.conf**
(restarted apache)

Changed db value in *ps_configuration*:

```
PS_SHOP_DOMAIN > myprestashop.com
PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL > myprestashop.com
```

*ps_shop_url*:

```
domain > myprestashop.com
domain_ssl > myprestashop.com
```

After entering domain name **myprestashop.com** the site redirects for https://myprestashop.com and lists **htdocs** folder (when I click into folder whatisthis, the url looks like this https://myprestashop.com/whatisthis/ and shows 404 error)

Other sites work perfectly with this virtualhost solution, only this prestashop project redirects. Does somebody had same issue, or have any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Have you regenerated the .htaccess from backoffice? By the way... I guess you have a mismatch in configuration. You tell to prestashop that the shop domain is myprestashop.com but you have placed in subfolder. So your shop phisically is in 'whatisthis' folder.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant reach the backend too. Btw, the subfolders path are included ... other projects are loaded correctly with this way